# cron expression in AWS CloudWatch: How to run once a week

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, cloudwatch

In Amazon AWS CloudWatch it is possible to run a rule according to a schedule that is defined in a cron expression.

The rules for this are outlined [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/ScheduledEvents.html).

After some trying around, I wasn't able to compose an expression that will run **once a week** (e.g. at 4 pm on Sunday). The following attempts were rejected by CloudWatch with the message `Parameter ScheduleExpression is not valid..`.

```
0 16 * * SUN *
0 16 * * 6 *
0 16 * * SUN-SUN *
0 16 * * 6-6 *
```

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Try 
    `0 16 ? * 1 *`
The question marks "says" that it must no be executed everyday, so it must check the week day value.

Comment: Works perfectly and makes sense. Just to confirm: Your expression selects Saturday (and not Sun)? Thanks!!

Comment: From the docs it seems to be 1-7 or SUN-SAT , a bit confusing since in UNIX 0 = SUN. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/ScheduledEvents.html

Comment: Hmm, yes I guess using `SUN` will then be the best option to avoid confusion. I tried that and it worked fine. The final expression is `0 16 ? * SUN *`.